# Cant get value outside of scope / function - Cypress

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, cypress

im new to cypress, Node and JavaScript but i have some knowledge in Python.

From a website i have to get the table, last column and then the highest price from it and the name (which is in the first column) of the highest price.

My idea : Save every price in an array. Save every name in a different array. Check for the highest price and with the index of the highest price i can also get the name.

My Problem : outside the each() the array loses its values even though it got declared outside of the each().

Thank you in advance!

```
    it('Get table and find highest price', function(){

    
       var allPrices = new Array();
       var names= new Array();

       //visit website (we need the last column of the first table)
       cy.visit('https://www.computerbase.de/thema/grafikkarte/rangliste/')


    
       // iterate through last column and save values in highestPrice
       cy.get('tr td:nth-child(9)').each(($e1, index) => {

           let currentPrice = $e1.text().split("€")[0] // 389 € (22) =>  389 

           // check if the string has a dot in it and remove it
           if(currentPrice.includes(".")){
               let currentPriceWithoutDot= currentPrice.split(".")
               currentPrice = currentPriceWithoutDot[0] + currentPriceWithoutDot[1]      // 1.129 => 1129
           }

              allPrices.push(currentPrice)         
       })
    
       cy.log(allPrices[3]) // check to see if values are saved but array is empty
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the log after a `then` to get the values.

```js
it('Get table and find highest price', function () {
  var allPrices = new Array()
  var names = new Array()

  //visit website (we need the last column of the first table)
  cy.visit('https://www.computerbase.de/thema/grafikkarte/rangliste/')

  // iterate through last column and save values in highestPrice
  cy.get('tr td:nth-child(9)')
    .each(($e1, index) => {
      let currentPrice = $e1.text().split('€')[0] // 389 € (22) =>  389

      // check if the string has a dot in it and remove it
      if (currentPrice.includes('.')) {
        let currentPriceWithoutDot = currentPrice.split('.')
        currentPrice = currentPriceWithoutDot[0] + currentPriceWithoutDot[1] // 1.129 => 1129
      }

      allPrices.push(currentPrice)
    })
    .then(() => {
      cy.log(allPrices[3]) // check to see if values are saved but array is empty
    })
})
```

Comment: Instead of putting the `.log()` in a `.then()`, you could chain the `.log()` after the `.each()`, as the `.each()` would block the `.log()` from running.